# Communication, High Availability and microservices

Tags: microservices, communication, api-design, high-availability

My understanding of microservices is that you can "just" spin-up multiple instances of the same service, as required.

My question is, then, if you have x instances of a microservice, spread over y servers, how does anything calling an API on the microservice know where to find it?

One approach I've seen is to have some kind of discovery service (fixed IP address that can route to an instance, like a load-balancer); but surely that just pushes the problem back a layer - the discovery service then needs to know where everything is / when it fails, etc.? And what about high-availability for the discovery service (if you have multiple instances of that, you're back to not knowing where anything is again)

Another approach might be to use pub/sub messaging, but again you still need to know where the queue manager is (with high-availability, etc.); so you've still essentially got the same problem - and responses to queries are trickier with that approach.

Another related issue is, if you have a microservice that is pulling from a STOMP feed, how would you make that HA? you can't just have x instances of that service, or you'll be subscribing and reading the data x times, which means you end up duplicating the data when it's passed on to downstream systems. So you would want some kind of active/passive approach to that, right? Which means you need something to manage that failover, which again gives a single point of failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a service registry where a service registers itself on startup. The registry may listen for broadcasts by other services for the registration events so the registry's location does not need to be fixed somewhere in the service.

All other Services can then use this registry to look up the available instances by querying the registry. The registry may also act as a DNS resolver so your services can use DNS to resolve other services by name and also automatically load balance between multiple hosts.

Another way may be to reverse the responibility and the service wanting to contact the other service broadcasts requests that are answered with the needed information by the other service (which basically is what DNS does).

One readily available solution to this is [Consul by Hashi Corp](https://www.consul.io). Have a look at the features it provides which may be additionally useful, e.g. healthchecks.

Comment: This answer pointed me to Zookeeper, which pointed me to Curator, which has a service discovery framework option in it - so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I did was the following:

I have each Service generate a *Table of Contents* at startup that is accessible as root resource (`.../{service}/`). 
In this ToC are all endpoints as Map.

Key is a (well-known) EndpointId, a Value always consists of

- `title`
- `href`
- `type` (mediaType)

so, basically a regular Link.

Magic lies in the `href`, where public host (DNS) is configurable as environment variable (Config Map for instance). Due to using DNS, LoadBalancing etc. is out of the equasion. But you could use this approach for internal IPs too.

This is good practice mentioned [here](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

> A REST API should be entered with no prior knowledge beyond the initial URI (bookmark) and set of standardized media types that are appropriate for the intended audience (i.e., expected to be understood by any client that might use the API). From that point on, all application state transitions must be driven by client selection of server-provided choices that are present in the received representations or implied by the user’s manipulation of those representations. The transitions may be determined (or limited by) the client’s knowledge of media types and resource communication mechanisms, both of which may be improved on-the-fly (e.g., code-on-demand). [Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.]

So each service has a root resource containing Links to all endpoints (sometimes templated).

This very same ToC gets reused by publishing it to a Kafka-Topic called "endpoints", where `key` is a (well-known) ServiceId ("fooService" or "fooService:1.2.3") and the `value` is its ToC.

Each Service also has reading access to the Topic (GlobalKTable), so when it wants to produce a Link to the FooService, he looks up its ToC in the GlobalKTable, looks up the endpoint by its Id, replaces templated variables with real values and is done, it does not alter the `type`, because it is assumed to be correct.

The cool thing here is (due to Kafkas GlobalKTable and QueryableKeyStores), that when FooService alters its endpoints (only in a non breaking way) all other services automatically produce the new links. A DNS change or renaming path segments will just work. renaming of parameters obviously not.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the idea that this could be done through Kafka